# Passing an array infunction gives me undefined in console

Tags: javascript, arrays

In below **javascript** code, if I only prints nums which is array pass to the function. it prints the array as well as gives undefined. So below logic gives an answer but in next line it prints out undefined.

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {

       let deceding = nums.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});


    for(let i = 0; i<deceding.length ; i++)
        {
            if(deceding[i]>deceding[i+1])
                {
                    console.log(deceding[i+1]);
                    break;
                }
        }


}
```

Comment: "in next line" ... next after what? are you running this in the console? your `getSecondLargest` function returns nothing, i.e. same as `return undefined` - therefore, that's what you see in the console, the result of calling your function

Comment: your code seems working in me. codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZgdye?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Pretend deceding is `[0, 1, 2]`.

You have `i < deceding.length`, so `i` will range between 0 and 2 (Less than length, which is 3).

Next you do `console.log(deceding[i + 1]);`, but for the later iterations of the loop i + 1 will be greater than 2 which is the last index of the array, meaning it is undefined. i.e, you try to get `deceding[3]` which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can you change an execute environment? I've never seen `undefined` in my node.

Answer (score -1):

I guest that you run this function on `chrome console`.
Actually your function is return nothing. So it is console `undefined`.
Is this the same what you got ? http://prntscr.com/hgma9g

[image]

The chrome console alway print out what returned from last line of code. So if this is an assignment or function call without return a value it will print `undefined`. So don't worry, your function worked as expected.

There is a way to by pass this by assign and return the value you want to log in the function. :)

Comment: Thank you for your support. actually this is hakerrank problem and it does not pass the test case because of undefined

Comment: Glad that helped. It's really nice if  you could mark my answer as correct answer btw :) . Or at least can upvote for my helpful info. Thanks in advance